# Can importing a bitcoin address retrieve the lost coins with it?

Tags: address

I wish to know if its possible to get the lost coins back if you retrieve the BITCOIN address to which they were sent?

Comment: We have no idea what you're talking about unless you tell us. What are "the lost coins"?

Answer (score 4):

If you have the private key for the address that holds the Bitcoin, you still have control over those coins and they wouldn’t be considered lost. If you sent bitcoin to an address for which you don’t have the private key, then you cannot retrieve them unless the owner of the private key to whom you sent them sends the Bitcoin back to your address or gives you the private key to their address.